# Inter font icon no showing

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the **Inter** font. I got it from **Google Fonts**. But It can't be shown. Seems like arrow doesn't see the font. You can see it.[image: sa]

Instead of the same arrow on **Google Inter Font page**

[image]

css:

```
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

   body{
     font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
   }

</style>
</head>
```

html:

```
<div> ↗</div>
<div >Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground. ↗</div>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: make sure you already put `* { font-family: inter }` in your css

Comment: Share your code. Show us what you have tried so far not just pictures

Comment: The thing is that text sees the font, but arrow doesn't

Comment: You might use this approach described here: ["Google Fonts - IBM Plex Sans and left/right arrows rendering"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66801221/google-fonts-ibm-plex-sans-and-left-right-arrows-rendering/76526243#76526243)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use custom fonts you should copy these fonts to your project folder, after that use this code of CSS to add them to your document

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: Inter;
  src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

replace this src with your font address you copy in your project

Answer (score 0):

just use this code: 
It's work for me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body{
     font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
   }
p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}
div{
font-family: Inter;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size:x-large;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div> ↗</div>
<div >Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground. ↗</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not bro. it show the arrow as it doesn't use the Inter font

Comment: it's done, bro. to see this, just change font-size to something like font-size:x-large and change color

Comment: check it out there:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter?selection.family=Inter:wght@300;400;700;800&sidebar.open&preview.text=Almost+before+we+knew+it,+we+had+left+the+ground.+%E2%86%97+%E2%86%97+%D0%BC&preview.text_type=custom

Answer (score 0):

Using the CSS API at https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2 uses a slightly lighter weight font than what the full TTF offers.

Possible solutions:

1. You can use either the `text=` parameter, to include all characters you care about as [detailed in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#optimizing_your_font_requests)

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&text=Almost%20befrwkni,hadgu.↗" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="font-family: Inter, sans-serif;">
  Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground. ↗
</div>
```

2. You can download the entire TTF for the family and self-host it with your website. You'd lose certain benefits like

   - optimizing the font for cross-browsers, providing the best format for each (woff, woff2, svg, ttf, etc.)
   - subsetting the font into commonly used Unicode sections to avoid loading big payloads (the entire font) when website only uses latin characters
   - potential updates that happen to fonts to fix issues such as legibility